# updating the correct spelling within the spellchecker

Tags: java, spell-checking

I am trying to make a spellchecking application. My code works in term of that it is able to detect when there is a spelling error, I done this by using a text file that contains large amount of words to compare the user input for correct/incorrect spelling. The issue is that I am trying to implement a way to give suggestions of what the wrong spelling could be, rather than just stating the spelling is incorrect.

```
public class SpellChecker2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a String"); 
        String userWord = input.nextLine();

        final String theDictionary = "dictionary.txt";
        String[] words = dictionary(theDictionary);
        boolean correctSpelling = checking(words, userWord);

        if (!correctSpelling) {
            System.out.println("Incorrect spelling");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("The spelling is correct");
        }
    }

    public static String[] dictionary(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
        final String fileName = "dictionary.txt";
        int dictionaryLength = 0, i = 0;

        try (Scanner dictionary = new Scanner(new File(fileName))) {
            while (dictionary.hasNextLine()) {
                ++dictionaryLength;
                dictionary.nextLine();
            }
        }
        String[] theWords = new String[dictionaryLength];
        try (Scanner dictionary = new Scanner(new File(fileName))) {
            while (dictionary.hasNextLine()) {
                theWords[i] = dictionary.nextLine();
                i++;
            }
        }
        return theWords;
    }

    public static boolean checking(String[] dictionary, String userWord) {
        for ( int i =0; i < dictionary.length; i++) {
            if (userWord.equals(dictionary[i])) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

overall I am happy with the result that it can detect wrong spelling but is there a way to give suggestions to the user input when the spelling is incorrect. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could pretty easily just write out in the system that the word is mispelled. And print out the word? In your example, I guess it would be to just return the word in the checking so that you may print it out then? From checking, simply return the word if it's incorrect?

Comment: The problem you're trying to solve is quite a hard one that even the spellchecker in Microsoft Office doesn't get right 100% of the time. Also consider that just because a word exists in a dictionary doesn't mean that it's the one that the writer intends.

Comment: @cathy liam Read https://norvig.com/spell-correct.html to implement a basic spell corrector. The post has code given in almost every famous language. This article is one of the classics written by Peter Norvig.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string distance measures like edit distance or levenshtein distance, to find which words in your dictionary are closest to the input word. This is a very basic form of spelling recommender, but is still a great addition to your task.

For example, if the input word is 'gat', the closest words can be 'mat', 'cat' etc. You can choose, to display at most n recommendations. You will easily find multiple resources to help you implement these algorithms.

Reference:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance